# RPi_Cam_Web_Interface doesn't works and shows wrong HTML site, how to fix?

Tags: pi-3b+, web-server, web-interface, html5

I wanted to stream from my RPi to a website that I can access over the IP address. The best solution seems to be RPi_Cam_Web_Interface. I followed the instructions on the elinux.org that seems to be the official instruction. (https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) On this website are also pictures of how it is supposed to look, but mine looks like this [image] Has someone an idea why it looks like this or how I can fix it?

Comment: Check your `/var/www`. If it is empty you may want to reinstall it (`./remove.sh` and then `install.sh`)

Comment: I did it wasn't empty. There was a directory called 'html' and in there were many images, text and PHP files. I also tried to remove and install it again but there was no difference.

Comment: It looks like your web-server does not serve the RPi-Cam-Web-Interface. Is this a clean installation of Raspbian? Are you sure you are accessing the correct IP address?

Comment: I am sure to access the correct. But still, doesn't work I decided to copy my python files to my Mac and delete and install Raspbian again hopefully it works.

Comment: I reinstalled everything and still the same. Could it be that I use Buster?

Comment: There is an opened issue related to the Buster you may find a solution there https://github.com/silvanmelchior/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface/issues/500

Comment: Just go to `http://IPADDRESS/html` instead of `http://IPADDRESS`